# How to playback a set of images sequentially in android?

Tags: java, android, playback

Is there a way to display a set of images sequentially with play back features? I was wondering if this is possible to be done on an imageview or videoview?

Comment: PlayBack means? Do you want to show the pictures in slide show?

Comment: use timer and update your imageview from timer, set time your want in schedule task

Comment: @BirajZalavadia can you elaborate a bit more on it please?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal playback as in to forward and rewind like in a movie?

Comment: images from where server or sdcard?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia images from an SDCARD

Comment: so you have the list of imagpath of sdcard and you want to show like slide show right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity

```
Timer myTimer;
String image[]; // array of imagePath
private int imagePostion;


class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (++imagePostion == image.length) {
                                imagePostion = 0;
                            }
                             imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image[imagePostion]));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
// change image every 2 seconds
public void startTimerTask() {
        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 0, 2000);

    }

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                image = {} // fille array with filePath




    }


@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        try {
            myTimer.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

// start slide show
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            startTimerTask(); // start slide show
        }
```

Comment: where should the startTImerTask be called?

Comment: what would be the initial value of imagePosition? sorry for the newb question

Comment: 0 will be the initial position

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) control together with a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the pictures playback using a `ViewPager` and i have already answered this here on SO. 
Although i have used the following technique to switch `fragments` but you can inflate images in the `fragment`:
You can check my answer on the following link:

[How to automatically switch pages using viewPager and Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612369/1773155)