# How to work with Trinea Android Auto Scroll ViewPager library?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, viewpagerindicator

I have copied the code from this link "https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager" to my project package & include it in one of my layout xml file. But i am unable to understand about how to add several slideshow images & dots to this custom widget so that the auto scroll slideshow like shown at the GitHub page must be achieved. Any help would be honestly appreciable as i can't found document explaining usage of this library.

Answer (score 1):

You have to 2 type view in your layout

- ViewPager (Image slideshow)
- Viewpageindicator (dots color)

when you try add more fragment in viewpager adapter so dot color (viewpagerindicator) will auto increase

More detail :

[Readmore here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610085/how-to-switch-automatically-between-viewpager-pages)