# ViewFlipper or ImageView for slideshow animation?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, slideshow, viewflipper

I am trying to replicate this [Prototype](https://dribbble.com/shots/1815592-Breather-2-0-OnBoarding)
I am currently using a view Flipper for the background to move (animate) but i am able to use the animate on the first image but not as the same in others images.

When the Slideshow starts again, the first image does not animate only. Is it because i am animating it in OnCreate()?

```
viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);



    fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();


    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-100.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(100);
    animation.setRepeatMode(100);

    bgone.startAnimation(animation); //bgone is the image1
    bgtwo.startAnimation(animation);
    bgthree.startAnimation(animation);
    bgfour.startAnimation(animation);
    bgfive.startAnimation(animation);
```

What do u reckon for duplicating the prototype ? any links will help

Comment: that thing is known as View Pager

Comment: We have a Widget called ViewFlipper also in Android. Which starts the slideshow when the activity loads. @VivekMishra

Comment: I know that but for easier implementation and to show white dots according to current screen , I would suggest to use View Pager

Comment: Can we use an autostart feature in Viewpager ? like viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true); @VivekMishra

Comment: @VivekMishra can u give me an example ? because i did try viewpager.setAutoStart() but its not a valid method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109698/discussion-between-suhail-parvez-and-vivek-mishra).

Comment: check this link for autostart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610085/how-to-switch-automatically-between-viewpager-pages